# How to debug the linux kernel panic by the reboot command

Tags: linux, busybox, reboot

I tried to reboot the linux by the reboot command on the prompt.

I think that the busybox normally executed the function 'static void halt_reboot_pwoff(int sig)' because of the following boot message.

```
# reboot
# Stopping network: OK
Saving random seed: OK
Stopping klogd: OK
Stopping syslogd: OK
umount: devtmpfs busy - remounted read-only
[ 1321.807085] UBIFS (ubi0:0): background thread "ubifs_bgt0_0" stops
The system is going down NOW!
Sent SIGTERM to all processes
Sent SIGKILL to all processes
Requesting system reboot
[ 1323.827308] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000250
[ 1323.835746] pgd = 52a87f0e
[ 1323.838390] [00000250] *pgd=00000000
[ 1323.842067] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT ARM
[ 1323.846953] Modules linked in:
[ 1323.849995] CPU: 0 PID: 138 Comm: init Not tainted 4.14.139.1 #5
```

But the kernel_restart() of the linux kernel is not executed.

Is there any fault point in the process which the busybox calls the sys_reboot()?

Which point should I check?